GUI Java Swing . Trying to get a string from one class into a jlable of another class
I'm trying to get an output from a bubble sort algorithm (which I'm currently doing with System.out.print) to be displayed in a JLabel in another class when I'm pressing a JButton.
I'm fairly new to Java so I don't really know that much but I think I need to make the string where the output is stored public but I don't know how without messing up the Bubblesort code.
Thanks in advance
I have three classes.
MainClass
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MeinFrame();
    }
}

MeinFrame
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MeinFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JButton button;
    JLabel ausgabe;
    
    MeinFrame(){

        //JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        //panel.setBackground(Color.gray);
        //panel.setBounds(0, 0, 480, 100);

        ausgabe = new JLabel();
        ausgabe.setBounds(200, 500, 720, 400);
        ausgabe.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN,25));
        ausgabe.setText("Test");

        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setText("Bitte Wähle eine Sortier Methode");
        label.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.PLAIN,25));
        label.setBounds(200, 0, 720, 100);

        button = new JButton();
        button.setBounds(200,100,100,50);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        button.setText("Bubble sort");
        button.setFocusable(false);

        this.setTitle("Sortier Algorythmen");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(720,480);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.add(label);
        this.add(button);
        //this.add(panel);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(ausgabe);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==button){
            BubbleSortNames.main(null);
        }
    }
}

BubblesortNames
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BubbleSortNames {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Namen aus der Tabelle Person
        String[] names = {"Schmitt", "Jakob", "Oray", "Gross", "Müller","Schütz","Knapp"};

        // Verweißt auf den Bubblesort das er Starten soll
        bubbleSort(names);

        // Ausgabe der sortierten Namen
        System.out.println("Alphabetisch sortierte Namen: " + Arrays.toString(names));
    }

    public static void bubbleSort(String[] array) {
        int n = array.length;
        boolean swapped;

        // Bubble Sort Algorithmus
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            swapped = false;

            for (int j = 0; j < n - 1 - i; j++) {
                if (array[j].compareTo(array[j + 1]) > 0) {
                    // Elemente tauschen
                    String temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                }
                System.out.println( Arrays.toString(array));
            }

            // Wenn in diesem Durchlauf keine Elemente getauscht wurden, ist die Liste bereits sortiert
            if (!swapped) break;
        }
    }
}

I tried to get the string from the Bubblesort class through a ActionListener. Sadly I cannot get access to the string.

You could just call BubbleSortNames.bubbleSort directly, and keep the list of names to sort inside of MeinFrame instead (that way you can both pass it to bubbleSort AND use it afterwards...). The main(String[] args) function is supposed to be used once per program for the main entry point, there's no need to have one in the BubbleSortNames class.

Here is working code made with minimal changes to your code. As you suggested, I added a public attribute to class BubbleSortNames. Method bubbleSort sets the value of that attribute.
I also added a couple of lines to class MeinFrame in order to display it on the screen and to terminate the application when you click on the X to close the application window.
I recommend that you study this tutorial.
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MeinFrame();
    }
}

class MeinFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JButton button;
    JLabel ausgabe;

    MeinFrame(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        //panel.setBackground(Color.gray);
        //panel.setBounds(0, 0, 480, 100);

        ausgabe = new JLabel();
        ausgabe.setBounds(200, 500, 720, 400);
        ausgabe.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN,25));
        ausgabe.setText("Test");

        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setText("Bitte Wähle eine Sortier Methode");
        label.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.PLAIN,25));
        label.setBounds(200, 0, 720, 100);

        button = new JButton();
        button.setBounds(200,100,100,50);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        button.setText("Bubble sort");
        button.setFocusable(false);

        this.setTitle("Sortier Algorythmen");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(720,480);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.add(label);
        this.add(button);
        //this.add(panel);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(ausgabe);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==button){
            BubbleSortNames.main(null);
            ausgabe.setText(BubbleSortNames.sortedNames);
        }
    }
}


class BubbleSortNames {
    public static String sortedNames;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Namen aus der Tabelle Person
        String[] names = {"Schmitt", "Jakob", "Oray", "Gross", "Müller","Schütz","Knapp"};

        // Verweißt auf den Bubblesort das er Starten soll
        bubbleSort(names);

        // Ausgabe der sortierten Namen
        System.out.println("Alphabetisch sortierte Namen: " + Arrays.toString(names));
    }

    public static void bubbleSort(String[] array) {
        int n = array.length;
        boolean swapped;

        // Bubble Sort Algorithmus
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            swapped = false;

            for (int j = 0; j < n - 1 - i; j++) {
                if (array[j].compareTo(array[j + 1]) > 0) {
                    // Elemente tauschen
                    String temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }

            // Wenn in diesem Durchlauf keine Elemente getauscht wurden, ist die Liste bereits sortiert
            if (!swapped) break;
        }
        sortedNames = Arrays.toString(array);
    }
}

This is how it looks before clicking on the button.

And after clicking the button.


M8 thank you so much <3
